# Trigger oracle table changes in C#.net

Tags: c#, oracle

I added a Oracle database as data connection to my C#.net solution to make a interface with actions like add/delete/change entries of a table.

But I also need to trigger this actions before they are committed to make some checks.

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work because the alert never pops up: (The table is displayed in a 'gridview' made through the GUI of Visual Studio with the functions update/delete/..)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet1TableAdapters.MY_TableAdapter _adpt = new DataSet1TableAdapters.MY_TableAdapter();
    DataSet1.MY_DataTable dtTable = new DataSet1.MY_DataTable();
    DataSet1.MY_Row row = (DataSet1.MY_Row)dtTable.NewRow();

    dtTable.MY_RowChanging += new DataSet1.MY_RowChangeEventHandler(dtTable_MY_RowChanging);
}


void dtTable_R_BROKER_SETTLEMENTRowChanging(object sender, DataSet1.MY_RowChangeEvent e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "showAsOfAlert", "alert('test');", true);

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```